# BETWEEN EQUIVALENT in LINQ

Tags: linq

I am looking LINQ equivalent for the following query

```
Select * from ct_rate
WHERE
'2010-10-01 00:00:00'
BETWEEN start_date and end_date;
```

ANY IDEA?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use two comparison operations:

```
DateTime date = new DateTime(2010, 10, 1);

var results = from rate in ct_rates
              where rate.StartDate <= date && rate.EndDate >= date
              select rate;
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use ordinary comparison operators

```
var result = ct_rates
    .Where(x => x.start_date <= myDate && x => x.endDate >= myDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```
var result = from context.ct_rate.Where(d => d.start_date >= "2010-10-01 00:00:00" && d.end_date <= "2010-10-01 00:00:00")
```

Comment: He never said the dates were stored as date objects

Comment: (That's why I said most likely - but string comparisons with dates are typically not what people want or expect)

Answer (score 0):

In our case, Robert's answer was close to what I was looking for.  In our data model, our 'end' or 'through' date columns are nullable.

Something like the following was needed:

```
Category.Where(
    w => w.ValidFrom <= now && 
   (w.ValidThru == null ? DateTime.MaxValue : w.ValidThru) >= now).Select(s => s).Dump();
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this works when wanting only to compare the data part.

```
var results = from rate in ct_rates
              where rate.StartDate.Date <= date && rate.EndDate.Date >= date
              select rate;
```