# Linq - Equivalent to BETWEEN inside a Left Join

Tags: c#, linq

I've seen this topic [BETWEEN EQUIVALENT in LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4054982/between-equivalent-in-linq)

My Original Query in SQL:

```
SELECT ISNULL(Tcar.name, '') FROM dbo.models model
LEFT JOIN cars Tcar on Tcar.model = model.id AND
                     Tcar.year between model.Start and model.End
```

I need to implement between inside a "left join", I tried this:

My Classes:

```
public class car
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int model { get; set; }
    public DateTime year { get; set; }
}

public class model
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime End { get; set; }
}
```

My Implementation:

```
var theModel = from model in models
               join Tcar in cars
                    on new
                        {
                            ID = (int)model.id,
                            DateStart = (DateTime)model.Start,
                            DateEnd = (DateTime)model.End
                        }
                     equals new                                 
                         {
                             ID = (int)Tcar.model,
                             DateStart = (DateTime)Tcar.year,
                             DateEnd = (DateTime)Tcar.year
                         } into tempCar
                       from finalCar in tempCar
               select new
                   {
                       CAR = (finalCar == null ? String.Empty : finalCar.name)
                   };
```

WorkAround:

```
var theModel = from model in models
               join Tcar in cars
                    on model.id equals Tcar.model
                where model.Start <= Tcar.year && model.End >= Tcar.year
               select new
                   {
                       CAR = Tcar.name
                   };
```

If I use a workaround Linq translate to this query:

```
SELECT Tcar.name FROM dbo.models model
LEFT JOIN cars Tcar on Tcar.model == model.id
WHERE model.Start <= Tcar.year and model.End >= Tcar.year
```

I can put a simple where before "select new", but I have to implement by this way, with "between" inside the left join, How can I do this ?

Comment: Totally unrelated, but you are violating the c# Naming Conventions. =) See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzf533w0(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Jeans this is a simple example to show for community.

Comment: Sure. =) I just find code easier for me to understand if it looks familiar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit - Added `DefaultOrEmpty()` in order for it to be a Left Join

Modify your query like so, this will force the where clause into the join on clause. It wont give you the Between clause in the Join, but at least there wont be a where clause

```
var theModel = from model in models
               from Tcar in cars.Where(x => model.id == x.model)
                                .Where(x => model.Start <= x.year && model.End >= x.year)
                                .DefaultOrEmpty()
               select new
                   {
                       CAR = Tcar.name
                   };
```

Comment: I have to use Join because I need to check if the Left Join Table has or not values. But Linq doesn't have this implementation :(

Comment: @Gandarez - This gets translated to a Join

Comment: this implements two tables in the "from", don't in the "Join".

Comment: I didn't show, but I need to implement Left Join, not Inner Join :(

Comment: @Gandarez - I updated my answer to use a Left Join instead of Inner Join

Comment: Can I join the Where? like: .Where(x => model.id == x.model && model.Start <= x.year && model.End >= x.year)

Comment: @Gandarez - Yes you can combine them into one, I think its easier to read when its split into two

Comment: You might as well use a join for the bit where you *can* use a model, surely... and why use an anonymous type for the final select?

Comment: @Jon Skeet - I used the same anonymous type that Gandarez used in his example. I feel using the double *from* with multiple *Where* statements and finally the *DefaultOrEmpty* the most readable way to write left joins in Linq. And the generated sql puts join critera in the *ON* instead of in a *Where* statement

Comment: @Aducci: Oh for *left* joins, that's absolutely right. Ignore my comments, I'd missed that the OP needed a left join.

Comment: Only change the select clause to-> CAR = (Tcar == null ? String.Empty : (string)Tcar.name)

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server should consider your original query and the example produced by LINQ to be identical, because `WHERE model.Start <= Tcar.year and model.End >= Tcar.year` and `ON Tcar.year between model.Start and model.End` both specify join conditions.

It's generally preferred to use `ON` because it keeps your join conditions separate from your other search criteria, but that's for readability rather than performance. Testing similar queries on a couple of tables I had lying around produces identical query plans, and I'd be surprised if you see different plans for your tables.